# How to create a nodejs app that keeps listening to ports and does not exist

Tags: node.js

I need a skeleton of NodeJS app that listens to a port and does not exit.

Normally when you execute a JS file, it exits after finishing executing. I think a `while(true) {}` is the wrong way to go.

Can you provide some code sample for non-exiting JS code? It is a little bit like NodeJS web server, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

[Use the built-in http library](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp):

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

After establishing a listener, unless an exception is thrown, execution will continue as the event loop waits for a message to be received.

You get much the same behavior if you were to do something with `setInterval()`. Since NodeJS knows there is an interval or pending action, it will continue execution until stopped or an exception is thrown.

Comment: It hides the part why it won't exist. I need to learn why this code won't exit in theory and practice. You may say "Read the code yourself". I know if I read the code I will be lost.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu `http.createServer` ... `listen` runs endless, doing what you mean with "no exit". You don't need to manage by yourself, the library already does.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js). The server connects and listens to a socket. Since the event loop is in use and technically has work left to do, the process will not close